# Button VisualBrush - using Icons properly

Tags: c#, wpf, user-interface

I am developing a MUI-style WPF application. I am using icons like e.g.: http://modernuiicons.com .

Now, If I use the following Code:

```
<Button x:Name="_ButtonSearch" Background="White" Grid.Column="3" Margin="20,20,20,20" Click="_ButtonSearch_Click" >
    <Button.OpacityMask>
         <VisualBrush Visual="{StaticResource appbar_magnify}" Stretch="Uniform"/>
    </Button.OpacityMask>
</Button>
```

with the following XAML for the "appbar_magnify":

```
<Canvas x:Key="appbar_magnify" Width="76" Height="76" Clip="F1 M 0,0L 76,0L 76,76L 0,76L 0,0">
    <Path Width="33.1464" Height="33.1465" Canvas.Left="21.8536" Canvas.Top="22" Stretch="Fill" Fill="{DynamicResource BlackBrush}" Data="F1 M 42.5,22C 49.4036,22 55,27.5964 55,34.5C 55,41.4036 49.4036,47 42.5,47C 40.1356,47 37.9245,46.3435 36,45.2426L 26.9749,54.2678C 25.8033,55.4393 23.9038,55.4393 22.7322,54.2678C 21.5607,53.0962 21.5607,51.1967 22.7322,50.0251L 31.7971,40.961C 30.6565,39.0755 30,36.8644 30,34.5C 30,27.5964 35.5964,22 42.5,22 Z M 42.5,26C 37.8056,26 34,29.8056 34,34.5C 34,39.1944 37.8056,43 42.5,43C 47.1944,43 51,39.1944 51,34.5C 51,29.8056 47.1944,26 42.5,26 Z "/>
</Canvas>
```

I get the following:

[image: The button in designer.]

As you see in the highlighting squares that I drew, the Button cuts of a small part of the icon. So when you clicked the button in the program it will look like this:

[image: the button in running code after you pressed it]

The parts that were cut off are now black. Does not look good.

So my question is, how can I improve this scenario?

Greetings

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't seem to find the exact reason . 
It is some how caused by ButtonChrome element inside the Button's Template .

You can do one of 2 things :

1) Override the button template.

```
   <Geometry x:Key="magnifierGeometry">F1 M 42.5,22C 49.4036,22 55,27.5964 55,34.5C 55,41.4036 49.4036,47 42.5,47C 40.1356,47 37.9245,46.3435 36,45.2426L 26.9749,54.2678C 25.8033,55.4393 23.9038,55.4393 22.7322,54.2678C 21.5607,53.0962 21.5607,51.1967 22.7322,50.0251L 31.7971,40.961C 30.6565,39.0755 30,36.8644 30,34.5C 30,27.5964 35.5964,22 42.5,22 Z M 42.5,26C 37.8056,26 34,29.8056 34,34.5C 34,39.1944 37.8056,43 42.5,43C 47.1944,43 51,39.1944 51,34.5C 51,29.8056 47.1944,26 42.5,26 Z </Geometry>

   <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
        <Path Stretch="Uniform" Data="{StaticResource magnifierGeometry}"  Fill="{TemplateBinding Foreground}"/>
        </ControlTemplate>
```

2 ) Pad it using  Viewport definition .

Notice a clearer way of creating an Opacity mask .

```
    <Button  Margin="20,20,20,20" BorderThickness="0">
        <Button.OpacityMask>
            <DrawingBrush  Stretch="Uniform" Viewport="0.05,0.05,0.9,0.9" >
                    <DrawingBrush.Drawing>
                        <DrawingGroup>
                            <DrawingGroup.Children>
                                <GeometryDrawing Brush="Blue"  Geometry="{StaticResource magnifierGeometry}" />                                             
                            </DrawingGroup.Children>
                        </DrawingGroup>
                    </DrawingBrush.Drawing>
                </DrawingBrush>
        </Button.OpacityMask>
    </Button>
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Looks much cleaner now!

Comment: A problem with this is that my Buttons get invisible when the Mouse enters the Button area. I think this has to do with the OpacityMask.

I went for Solution 2.

@eran

Comment: It has to do with the button chrome . 
override the default template . i.e. the first solution .
come to think about it  , the second soloution will only work if you did the first to achive a default button style. and only then applied an image.

Comment: Thank you so far, but I have trouble implementing the first solution. I cant find where I put this inside my xaml. The component is a UserControl. @eran

Comment: read about creating styles and templates in wpf , it's the default button template. 
 I Gave you it's new content.

Comment: I found it. problem is that I have to create one style for each button that I want like that and I cant change the color of the buttons in code behind at runtime. @eran

Comment: I understand , i'll post something a bit more comprehensive tomorrow

Comment: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/knom/archive/2007/10/31/wpf-control-development-3-ways-to-build-an-imagebutton.aspx